# Prove that the expectation of the number of black balls preceding the first white ball is $\frac {b}{w+1}$

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Balls are taken one by one out of an urn containing $w$ white and $b$ black balls until the first white ball is drawn. Prove that the expectation of the number of black balls preceding the first white ball is $\frac {b}{w+1}$

**Attempt:** Let $X_i$ be the random variable that denotes the number of black balls that are drawn at the $i_{th}$ step before a white ball is drawn.

Then, the total number of such balls $ X= X_1 +  \cdots+X_n \implies E(X)=\sum E(X_i).$

$E(X_i)= 1 \cdot \dfrac {^bC_r}{^{b+w}Cr}\cdot \dfrac {^wC_1}{^{b+w-r}C_1}$

Thus, $\sum E(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{b} ~ 1 \cdot \dfrac {^bC_r}{^{b+w}Cr}\cdot \dfrac {^wC_1}{^{b+w-r}C_1}$

Could someone please tell me if I attempted this correctly? Because I get a very complicated answer in the end after evaluating the above.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Isn't $X_i=i$? I think you are over complicating things.

Comment: @Vasya Yeah, I feel a bit confused now. Could you give me a direction please? I  have complicated it

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of black balls preceding the first white ball. Then clearly we have
$\mathbb P(X=0) = \frac w{w+b}$. For $1\leqslant n\leqslant b$ we can show by induction that
$$
\mathbb P(X=n) = \frac w{w+b}\cdot\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}b-i}{\prod_{i=1}^n w+b-i}.
$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &= \sum_{n=0}^b n\cdot\mathbb P(X=n)\\
&=\frac w{w+b}\cdot \sum_{n=1}^b\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}b-i}{\prod_{i=1}^n w+b-i}\\
&=\frac b{w+1}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for answering. There is one thing which is confusing me. Why is the probability of finding a black ball at any step always = $\frac {w}{w+b}$. If a black ball had been recovered in previous steps, the probability will definitely change?

Comment: The probability of finding a black ball at any step is *not* always $\frac w{w+b}$, but it is a common factor that can be pulled out.